# if I create 'front-page.php', then how do I link to post index?

Tags: posts, links, frontpage

I want to have a custom front page and a blog page. So I created the `front-page.php` file, which will include my custom markup. I don't want to have blog post index on my front page, so I created `home.php` to feature blog posts index. How do I link to the blog page in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since WordPress 4.5 you can use [`get_post_type_archive_link( 'post' )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type_archive_link/) to link to the page containing the blog posts. Depending on what you've set under Settings -> Reading, this will be either the front page, e.g. `example.com/` or a specific page like `example.com/news/`. [`home_url( '/' )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/home_url/) always points to the front page.

Comment: after I've created `home.php` (given that`front-page.php` also exists), do I still have to add new blank page in admin panel and point to it in `settings>reading>static page>blog page`, in order to have blog posts index appear in `home.php`?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise how would WordPress know where the blog page is and when to load `home.php`?